# Android.jar is missing in Package explorer in all my projects

Tags: android, eclipse

My computer crashed and when I opened Eclipse, I saw no android package. First off, I am curious what happened?! None of my projects has Android package. Anyone know what happened?
And how can I fix that?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaS2h.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened to me too, in Eclipse click on Projects>Clean Project and clean them all, now close and open your project, and all will be well. That once solved my problem.